# Knex.js batch insert handle onConflict merge

Tags: javascript, database, knex.js

I had a case where I was saving 1800 rows at once and as the data grow it started to cause some issues. Then I started to use .batchInsert() which was working properly. Now I have to handle conflicts also. What is the best way to handle conflicts with batchInserts.
This is the code I have.

```
return db
  .batchInsert(payload, "payments", 1000)
  .onConflict("batch_id")
  .merge()
  .returning("*");
```

However, I am getting

> db.batchInsert(...).onConflict is not a function

Any workarounds over this?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?